# Solution to a differential equation with steady states dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am wondering if anyone knows something about equations that look like this
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \prod_{q_k \in \mathbb{Q} } (x-q_k)$$
Where $q_k$ is an enumeration of the rationals. This has infinitely many steady states which are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ but the behavior of the solution really depends on whether or not these are stable or alternatively what happens on the irrationals.

Comment: It is interesting but the right hand side does not make sense, it is a non convergent infinite product.

Comment: What do you mean by non-convergent?

Comment: It is an infinite product. Just like an infinite sum, it makes no sense as a number, unless it is convergent. But that one is not. The necessary condition for the convergence of an infinite product $\prod_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is that $a_k\to 1$. In your case this does not happen for any $x\in\mathbb R$.